# A potentially dangerous place in pytorch code, which leads to producing NaNs

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, nan

I am trying to implement Bidirectional LSTM in PyTorch, and the implementation of forward method looks as follows:

```
def forward(self, inputs):
    word_embeddings = self.embedding.forward(inputs)

    output = torch.zeros((inputs.shape[0], inputs.shape[1], self.tagset_size))

    #init hidden states for LSTM
    hidden_state_L = []
    hidden_state_R = []

    hidden_state_L.append(torch.zeros(inputs.shape[1], self.lstm_hidden_dim))
    hidden_state_R.append(torch.zeros(inputs.shape[1], self.lstm_hidden_dim))

    if next(self.parameters()).is_cuda:
      output = output.cuda()
      hidden_state_L[0] = hidden_state_L[0].cuda()
      hidden_state_R[0] = hidden_state_R[0].cuda()

    for i, word in enumerate(word_embeddings):
      hidden_state_L.append(self.tanh.forward(self.fc_xh_L.forward(word) + self.fc_hh_L.forward(hidden_state_L[-1])))

    for i, word in enumerate(reversed(word_embeddings)):
      hidden_state_R.append(self.tanh.forward(self.fc_xh_R.forward(word) + self.fc_hh_R.forward(hidden_state_R[-1])))

    hidden_state_L.pop()
    hidden_state_R = hidden_state_R[1:][::-1]
      
    for idx, (h_L, h_R) in enumerate(zip(hidden_state_L, hidden_state_R)):
      output[idx - 1] = self.fc_hy.forward(torch.cat([h_L, h_R], dim = 1))
    
    return output
```

In my implementation the hidden states are stored in lists, and then from the list I get activations. The training process makes an epoch and a half, reaching an accuracy of approximately 80%, and then the neural network loss becomes NaN and the training fails. Where is a potentially risky place, or maybe one can suggest more sensible way, than these lists? Or there may be some caveats with the computations on the device?

I would be grateful for possible suggestions

Comment: Please show the definition of your loss function

Comment: @Omni `criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().cuda() `

Comment: @Omni the call looks as follows -                                                                               `logits = model(X_batch)
 loss = criterion(logits.permute(0, 2, 1), y_batch)`

Comment: Did you check the maximum absolute weight value and the maximum absolute gradient value? Those are usually good indicators as to whether the problem is an implementation error, a numerical instability in the implementation or conceptual problems like missing regularization where needed or exploding gradients due to the architecture design.